# How can i order the output of "echo" command

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I have created one script with shell scripting and the output of the script is :

[image]

but i want to be the output is like this :

[image]

and the code is :

```
if [ $CS == 0 ]; then
printf $BLUE
echo "$url$i            [Found]"
else
printf $RED
echo "$url$i            [Not Found]"
fi
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you looking for the output to be aligned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already using `printf` in the `true` branch of your `if` statement, which supports formatted output. How about something like this, assuming `$CS` contains the truth value of your "Found" vs "Not Found" condition:

```
printf "$color%-50s%s$RESET\n" "$url" "$status"
```

Where `$color` is the ANSI code for the desired color, `$RESET` is the ANSI code `\e[0m` and `$url` and `$status` are the URL string and the [Found] or [Not Found] status strings, respectively.

Here's a full example. Note I've used `sh` in the shebang, but this is fully compatible with bash syntax as well:

```
#!/bin/sh

BLUE="^[[0;34m"
RED="^[[0;31m"
RESET="^[[0m"

CS=0

for url in http://example.com/foo http://example.com/longer_address ; do
    if [ $CS -eq 0 ]; then
        color=$BLUE
        status='[Found]'
    else
        color=$RED 
        status='[Not Found]'
    fi

    printf "$color%-50s%s$RESET\n" "$url" "$status"

    CS=1 # Change truth condition for next test
done
```